# Minify returns white page after source file changes

Tags: php, minify

[Minify](https://code.google.com/p/minify/) works fine for me, but after changing one of the source files, I receive a white empty page. Refreshing the page does not change anything. Refreshing without caching (Strg + F5) solves the problem. After one refresh without caching, I can go back refreshing with caching and it works.

The URL im calling looks like this:

> dev/min/min.php/js?type=js&src%5B0%5D=ewOutlibs%2Fjquery.min.js&src%5B1%5D=ewOutlibs%2Fcookie%2Fjquery.cookie.js

**min.php**

```
<?php
define('MINIFY_MIN_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));

// load config
require MINIFY_MIN_DIR . '/config.php';

// autoload
require $min_libPath . "/Minify/Loader.php";
Minify_Loader::register();

// caching
Minify::setCache(
    isset($min_cachePath) ? $min_cachePath : ''
    ,$min_cacheFileLocking
);

// get files to merge
$aSrc = $_GET['src'];

// replace shortened url with long url
if (isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] === 'js') {
    $aSrc = str_replace('ewOut', '//out/xxx/src/js/', $aSrc);
}

// build array
$aSources = array(
    'files' => $aSrc,
    'maxAge' => 31536000 // one year
);

try {
    // compress, merge and serve new file
    Minify::serve('Files', $aSources);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Request Header:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:oxidadminprofile=0%40Standard%4010%401; oxidadminlanguage=de; sid_key=oxid; language=0; sid=crlrs8bqg21g6e33arsjq708k4; ZDEDebuggerPresent=php,phtml,php3
Host:dev.teltec
If-Modified-Since:Tue, 04 Aug 2015 12:35:59 GMT
If-None-Match:"pub1438691759;gz"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36
```

Response Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Tue, 04 Aug 2015 12:36:04 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8o mod_fcgid/2.3.9
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
ETag: "pub1438691759;gz"
Expires: Wed, 03 Aug 2016 12:36:04 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Set-Cookie: ZDEDebuggerPresent=php,phtml,php3; path=/
```

Comment: Anything interesting in your error_log? Minify compares file mtimes with server time to decide if files have changed. Make sure if you change files the mtimes get updated.

Comment: `mtime` is updated correctly. The only interesting line in php_error.log is `[10-Aug-2015 07:09:45 UTC] PHP Warning:  strtotime() [<a href='function.strtotime'>function.strtotime</a>]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Paris' for '2.0/DST' instead in min\lib\HTTP\ConditionalGet.php on line 358`.

Comment: I locally defined Europe/Berlin as the timezone, at it seems to work now. But the problem is still present on our staging server, which already has Europa/Berlin defined as the timezone. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tmp directory on the stage system was not writeable, so Minify failed caching the files and returned a white page. Silly mistake.
Locally worked fine, because the tmp directory worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the server and/or browser is caching it. You invalidate the cache when the source updates, but the browser thinks it's still cached, tries to reference it, shows blank until you force a refresh (ctrl+F5). A way around it is to make the URL you use to access it unique by way of a "version" number. Microsoft uses it with their bundles (the hash changes if the source file changed) which automatically tells the browser to go fetch a "new" copy of it.

I had the same problem with XML feeds I was providing to a client who kept getting the same copy of it until I just added a version number at the end forcing the browser to always fetch a new file

Comment: Shouldn't that automatically be solved by the Minify library?`

Comment: No. It depends on how you access it, and as far as I can tell, your URL has no way to be unique enough for the browser, or the server, to determine that the content has changed so it is forced to get a new copy. This is apparent when you have to press Ctrl+F5 to reload it. Do yourself a favor and test it by adding a random number parameter to the same url and see if it happens or not to prove my theory. minify minify's, it doesn't do "cache busting" for you :)

Comment: Minify has a caching mechanism implemented, and as far as I know, it works quite well. The browser always gets the cached file and if I change one of the source file, Minify generates a new version of the minified file. So it detects changes in the soruce files and should then correctly deliver the new file. I could fix my problem by definining a timezone directly in the php.ini, but on our staging server the problem still occurs, even with this setting. Maybe my `min.php` already contains some errors?

Comment: You don't understand. Even if minify has it's own caching mechanism, the server (apache/nginx) AND the browser ALSO has their own caching mechanisms. What you're running into is the fact that the browser is caching the file, not minify itself. If a browser sees www.hello.com/?what=true the next time that is hit, it will think it's the same url and dish out the cached version (especially if the browser is IE) and won't bother requesting the server give it a new file

Comment: Well, then I dont know how to fix this issue. I could put a timestamp to the end of the URL, but then Minify will automatically rebuild everything every request, what I dont want. The minified and combined files are located in a tmp folder. The perfect way would be to append a timestamp/versoion number, which is only updated if the source files actually have changed.

Comment: That's exactly what I said. A version number is required, however a timestamp would work too, because minify only rebuild if the source changes, so appending some kind of random number to the URL the browser calls, would force it to not use the browser cached version, minify however, will only rebuild when the SOURCE changes. Browsers cache. HTTP Servers cache. CDN's cache. Then you have minify who also "caches" the output to a tmp folder. There's several layers to this. YOUR problem is your browser is caching it. And to "bust" this and force the browser to ask for a new file

Comment: Then can you tell me please, why it's working locally when I set a timezone in the php.ini (see comments below my question) without any timestamp?

Comment: because IE (or any browser) handles local intranet caching different to external websites. Dude. Is this your first time programming for the web or something? If you just did what I said already you could have moved on with this problem. I've been doing this going on 17 years now. I've had this exact same issue before, and I've solved this exact same issue several times, with the junior programmers under me struggling through to some senior guys. If you don't want to listen, then go ahead, struggle. I'm done.

Comment: "Dude", I just solved the error. It had nothing to do with your assumption (sadly), just the tmp directory was not writeable, so Minify could not cache the files. And yes, Minify does cache the files correctly, so everything works as expected :)